# How can I read a text file and save the numbers inside a group to a 5 different lists in python

Tags: python

I have a text file that basically have this structure:

```
 Transactions/Sec for Group = AA\CODE1\KB

 100

 200

 300


 400


 500


 Transactions/Sec for Group = AB\CODE2\KB


 800


 300


 400


 500


 600


 Transactions/Sec for Group = AC\CODE3\KB


 400


 300


 500


 600


 700


 Transactions/Sec for Group = AD\CODE4\KB


 200


 200


 300


 400


 400
```

I would like to read each group and save the 5 numbers in 5 different lists. For example, read group 1, and create list 1, list 2, list 3, list 4, list 5. Read group 2, and the numbers from list 2, "append" them in list 1, list 2, list 3, list 4, list 5...

This is what I did:

```
with open('Output.txt') as foutput:

    count = 0
    list1 = []
    list2 = []
    list3 = []
    list4 = []
    list5 = []
    for line in foutput:
        #print line
        count = count + 1

        if 'Group' in line:             
            key = line[line.index('=')+1:].strip()
            #f.write(key)
        else:   
            value = float(line.strip()) 
            list1 = value                                               
            ind += 1
            list2 = float(line.strip() + '\n')
```

The code is not working, basically I have the 5 numbers in 1 list, and I need each number in different lists....

It doesnt give me any error for having all the numbers in 1 list....(or in 1 variable, that is the value variable)

Thank you for the help.

Comment: I think you mean to append value to list1 but not sure what you intend to put in list2 and the other lists.  Also (line.strip() + '\n') surely won't be convertible to float because of the '\n'.

Comment: @TrisNefzger I mean to append each number in 5 different lists. From group 1: number 1 append to list 1, number 2, append to list 2, number 3 append to list 3, number 4 append to list 4, number 5 append to list 5. From group 2, again, number 1 append to list 1, number 2 append to list 2, number 3 append to list 3 , etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we can assume the file will be a constant format every time, we can do this. I'm going to use a dict instead of five lists, and use the item after the = as the key.

```
f = open("Output.txt", "r")
lines = [line.rstrip() for line in f if line != "\n"] #Get all lines, strip newline chars, and remove lines that are just newlines.
lines.close()

NUM_LISTS = 5

groups = [[] for i in range(NUM_LISTS)] 
listIndex = 0 
for line in lines:
    if "Transactions/Sec for Group" not in line:
        groups[listIndex].append(float(line))
        listIndex += 1
        if listIndex == NUM_LISTS:
            listIndex = 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I just have a question. I was trying to do this with 5 different lists, because I need to have the 5 list (5 groups of numbers) as a parameter for another process. How could I use your dictionary if I want to use the 5 groups separate?

Comment: Do you want to pass the list as an argument? If so, you can just get the list by doing groups[myCodeHere], and it will spit out the list.

Comment: Is giving me an error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1011.5032'.

Comment: replace the call to int with a call to float. From what you posted, I assumed they would only be whole numbers.

Comment: Hi @ollien your code worked but is doing what I already did... maybe I didnt explain myself clear....I will explain it again. The first group has 5 numbers, I wanted to append each number in each list. The first number append it to list 1, second, to list 2, third to list 3, four to list 4 and fitth to list 5.... when I read the second group, the first number from the second group should go to list 1, the second number to list 2, the third number to list 3, etc...so basically list 1 will have the first number of group 1 and the first number of group 2 and the same with the rest of the groups..

Comment: Basically your code is doing something similar of what I was doing before, saving the 5 numbers in a dictionary... I was saving them in a variable...

Comment: thats why I look to do it with 5 different list... because that way I can use the lists later and send them as parameters....

Comment: What do you want to happen with the Group = AB\... portion? Does it need to be stored?

Comment: no I dont need to store it...but I created a key just to have it there if I need to use it in the future

Comment: Should be updated now. NUM_LISTS should be the number of lists you want, in this case 5.

Comment: thank you . Quick question, so I have NUM_LIST = 5...  if you want to print list 4... how would I print it?

Comment: You would do groups[3]

Comment: I saw it. I deleted my other comment, Im sorry, I was working all day. Thank you again!!!!!

Comment: Thanks! If this answered your questions, would you please mark it as accepted? It's what we do on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to ignore empty lines. The `.strip()` does not remove them. So, you have to use a condition to do that.

I have a code example here, it works for me (python2.7).

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re

#Input file handle.
input_file = open('file.txt', 'r')

#Declare the dictionary with all lists: Group name as key, num sequence as value.
lists = {}

#For each line.
for line in input_file:
    #Re to remove empty lines.
    if re.match(r'^\s*$', line):
        string = "The line is emty, next one."
        next
    #Needed line.
    else:
        if "Group =" in line:
            #split() to use space as spliter.
            group_name = line.strip().split()[-1]
            #Init lists[group_name] to an empty list.
            lists[group_name] = []
        else:
            lists[group_name].append(int(line.strip()))

print lists
```

It prints :

```
{'AB\\CODE2\\KB': [800, 300, 400, 500, 600], 'AC\\CODE3\\KB': [400, 300, 500, 600, 700], 'AA\\CODE1\\KB': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500], 'AD\\CODE4\\KB': [200, 200, 300, 400, 400]}
```

As mentioned, the file format has to be constant.

***EDIT*** : As I read, you have to use these 4 lists as parameters. You have 2 options :

1. Use the `.items()` of a dictionary which gives you:

   ```
   [('AB\\CODE2\\KB', [800, 300, 400, 500, 600]), ('AC\\CODE3\\KB', [400, 300, 500, 600, 700]), ('AA\\CODE1\\KB', [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]), ('AD\\CODE4\\KB', [200, 200, 300, 400, 400])]
   ```

And then, to use lists as argument for you function, you can do `lists.items()[0][1], lists.items()[1][1], lists.items()[2][1] and lists.items()[3][1]`.

2. Use a transformation of you dictionary in a list if you are more
   confortable with it :

   ```
   list_of_lists = []
   for list_name in lists.keys():
       list_of_lists.append(lists[list_name])
   print list_of_lists
   ```

It will give you:

```
[[800, 300, 400, 500, 600], [400, 300, 500, 600, 700], [100, 200, 300, 400, 500], [200, 200, 300, 400, 400]]
```

Comment: Your code is doing what I was doing. Basically what I needed is this: I have group 1 and 5 numbers, so save the first number from group 1 to a list, the second number to a second list, the third number to a third list, the fourth to a fourth list and the fifth number to a fifth list. When I read group 2, the first number from group 2, goes to the list 1, the second number to list 2, the third number to list 3.... etc.... so list number 1, will have the first number of all the groups, list 2, will have the second number of all the groups .....

Comment: Ah okay.. Now it is a little bit more clear. :)
From the dictionary, you can extract what you want, but you already have accepted the previous answer so.. you have what you want! 

Have a nice day.